# How should I display a table with an XML data source?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I had a CSV file that I converted to XML. I would like to use this data for a table on my web page. What is the best way to tackle this?

Thanks.
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly suggest using JQuery for this, it makes it pretty painless.

[Here is a walkthrough](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2007/10/10/jquery-and-xml.html) of loading an xml file through an ajax request and adding its contents to an ordered list.  You should be able to adapt it pretty easily to append to a table instead of a list.